# Regex(Dataannotation) for digits not repeating more than five times in string

Tags: c#, regex, model, data-annotations

I am just looking forward to create a regex which is not having consecutive digits repeating more than five times as well as it should start from only 6,7,8,9 digits.

I have solution but I'm using below 2 regex and validating.

```
string startPattern = "^[6-9][0-9]{9}$";
string endPattern = "([\\d])\\1{5}";
```

Please help, so that I can use as dataannotations in model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^(?!.*(\d)\1{5})[6-9]\d{9}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2GE9Ev/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!.*(\d)\1{5})` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there are identical 6 digits after any  0+ chars other than newline chars
- `[6-9]` - `6` to `9` digit and then
- `\d{9}` - nine digits
- `$` - and end of string.

Comment: How to change above regex, to not to allow 5 consecutive digits at start and end of string , but to allow in middle of string.Please help.

Comment: @Shilpa I am not sure what exact requirements you want to implement, but if they are the same as in the question, you may use [`^(?!(\d)\1{4})(?!.*(\d)\2{4}$)[6-9]\d{9}$`](https://regex101.com/r/2GE9Ev/2). I see you posted a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63682747/3832970).

Comment: Stribizew, thanks for the help.  This  is what exactly I want.