# Regex to not allow consecutive digits at start and end but to allow middle of string

Tags: regex

The regex **^(?!.*(\d)\1{5})[6-9]\d{9}$**  will not allow more than 5 consecutive same digits. but how to change regex to allow 6 consecutive digits in middle but not at start and end of string.

The regex should accept 6 consecutive same digits in middle of string like from 9888888654 and should not accept at the start of string like 9999994567 and at end of string like 9873555555

Please help.

Comment: This pattern will not match 123456789 which has no consecutive same digits at all: https://regexr.com/5b6s1

Comment: I think you can use 2 negative lookaheads `^(?!(\d)(?:\1{5}|.*(\d)\2{5}$))[6-9]\d{9}$` https://regex101.com/r/HavUEe/1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regular Expression for Same Consecutive Numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42001668/regular-expression-for-same-consecutive-numbers)

Comment: To clarify and help with thinking, please provide several examples of strings which should and should not match. Ideally many examples which at first glance look like they should match but don't and vice versa.

Comment: @NirAlfasi The OP already uses a pattern for consecutive matches, so that duplicate does not solve the problem.

Comment: The regex should accept 6 consecutive same digits in middle of string like from 9888888654 and should not accept at the start of string like 9999994567 and at end of string like 9873555555

Comment: IMHO there is nothing unclear about this question. It shows what the user has tried, and describes the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could test for 6 consecutive numbers and check if what follows are either 4 or zero characters.

```
^(?!.*(.)\1{5}(.{4}|$))[6-9]\d{9}$
```

See the demo [online](https://regex101.com/r/8EFOW7/1)

---

- `^` - Start string ancor.
- `(?!` - Open negative lookahead:

  - `.*` - Zero or more characters other than newline.
  - `(.)` - Capture your digit that needs to be checked against.
  - `\1{5}` - Match what is captured 5 times.
  - `(.{4}|$)` - Check what follows are either 4 characters or end string ancor.
  - `)` - Close negative lookahead.
- `[6-9]` - Match a digit between 6-9.
- `\d{9}` - Match nine more digits.
- `$` - End string ancor.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a negative lookahead asserting that the string does not start or end with 6 consecutive digits.

```
^(?!(?:(\d)\1{5}|.*?(\d)\2{5}$))[6-9]\d{9}$
```

In parts

- `^` Start of the string
- `(?!` Negative lookahead

  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `(\d)` Capture **group 1**, match 1 digit
    - `\1{5}` Repeat 5 times the value captured in group 1
    - `|` or
    - `.*?(\d)` Match 0+ times as least a possible and capture a digit in **group 2**
    - `\2{5}$` , repeat 5 times the value captured in group 2 till the end of the string
  - `)` Close non capture group
- `)` Close lookahead
- `[6-9]` Match a digit 6-9
- `\d{9}` Match 9 digit 0-9
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tl0gUK/1)